# Memory running consistently high on media temple VPS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, vps, memory-usage

I have a standard mediatemple VPS

- 512Mb RAM
- CPU  GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Xeon(R)CPU L5630 @ 2.13GHz
- Version  Parallels Plesk Panel v10.1.1_build1010110120.18 os_CentOS 5
- OS   Linux 2.6.18-028stab091.2

It's presently running a simple small website with about 100 (peak 171) visits a day yet the server memory usage is consistently redlining.

Is this normal behavior, if not how do I go about tracking down the culprit, or do i simply not have enough RAM?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a few hundred requests per day, you should not see memory issues - or, indeed, any issues of any kind.

This is more than likely bad PHP scripts leaking memory, and worker processes never recycling.

If this is running the apache prefork MPM, set MaxrequestsPerChild to 10 or so, and see what effect this has.